# How do i open a submenu via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mmenu

I am trying to open a submenu after the page is rendered, but no luck. I have tried adding a class `'mm-opened'` to the `<li` but it doesn't work.

Various methods via javascript on the `DOMContentLoaded Event`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var elementSelected = document.getElementById("liControl");
  if (elementSelected !== null) {
    elementSelected.classList.add("mm-opened");
  }
```

I expected the code to make the submenu open, but nothing happens

Comment: You cannot add class and make it work. You should call mmenu using it's js. Check example from https://mmenujs.com/examples.html

Comment: Try using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){new Mmenu("#liControl");});`

Comment: I did look at the examples, but can't see any examples that opens a submenu via code.

Also tried the code mentioned by @hev1 but that disappears the submenu option.

Just to add some more info, i already have the submenu rendered in the layout page, when a user clicks on an item (inside a submenu), the relevant page is opened, but the menu reset's itself to its orignal parent menu. (The mmenu is being rendered from a layout page which is shared across multiple pages). I am trying to target the event in the page to trigger a submenu opening (after the main parent menu is rendered)..

Comment: @MohammedMahmood Take a look at this: https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/api.html